# How convert object list into map?

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary

I want to convert array of objects with fields `name` and `value` into map and I have no idea how to do this.
I get:

```
[
    {"name": "key1", "value": "value1"},
    {"name": "key2", "value": "value2"},
    {"name": "key3", "value": "value3"}
]
```

But I need to send in request:

```
[
    {"key1": "value1"},
    {"key2": "value2"},
    {"key3": "value3"}
]
```

Comment: Can you share some code of what you tried? Are you using vanilla JS or Typescript?

Comment: `arr.map(({name, value}) => ({[name]: value}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Array.map`:

```
const output = input.map(
  (row) => ({[row.name]: row.value})
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this **:**

```js
const arr = [
    {"name": "key1", "value": "value1"},
    {"name": "key2", "value": "value2"},
    {"name": "key3", "value": "value3"}
];

const res = arr.map((obj) => {
    return {[obj.name]: obj.value}
});

console.log(res);
```